# UICollectionView second page content showing on first page

Tags: ios, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

[image]

For some reason, when I'm on the first page of UICollectionView,
it shows the images from the second page.

And I also noticed that the page isn't centered....

I manually set the

```
 pageControl.numberOfPages = 3
```

So I have three pages of images.
And each page displays 8 items (well...ideally).

This is in ViewDidLoad:

```
 UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout=[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];  
 [layout setSectionInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 15, 10)];
 [layout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];
 [self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:layout];
 self.collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:keyboardRect collectionViewLayout:layout];
 self.collectionView.dataSource = self;
 self.collectionView.delegate = self;
 self.collectionView.pagingEnabled = true;
 self.collectionView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = true;
 self.collectionView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(keyboardRect.size.width , keyboardRect.size.height);
 self.collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false;
 UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"TopCell" bundle:nil];
 [self.collectionView registerNib:cellNib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];
 [self.collectionView registerClass:[TopCollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];
 [self.collectionView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
 [self.view addSubview:self.collectionView];
```

When I tried to increase left and right inset from

```
 [layout setSectionInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 15, 10)];
```

It just made things worse. It'd only look okay on the first page,
but then the second and third pages would look off.

And here are some of my code:

```
-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  return [self.Images count];
}


-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  return CGSizeMake(70, 70);
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView* )collectionView {
  return 3;
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: set pagingEnabled = TRUE for collectionview and check.

Comment: It is set to true. (code above)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show only one section images in each page, then you have to modify

`-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method.

You have to return a more generic size.

`CGSize returnSize = CGSizeMake(screenWidth / 2 - insets, screenWidth / 2 - insets)`

Here inset represents the interItemSpacing for each item. screenWidth is collectionView width.

Answer (score 0):

If you want use the horizontal style of collectionView,you need to custom layout.
Here are some sample code you can use, and I have uploaded custom layout code on github.

```
FCEmoticonViewLayout *layout = [[FCEmoticonViewLayout alloc]init];
layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(itemWidht, itemWidht);
layout.itemSpacing = 15;
layout.lineSpacing = 15;
layout.numberOfColumn = 5;
layout.numberOfRow = 2;
self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout;
```

https://gist.github.com/Heisenbean/a0de38c1379a9d6a83f09ba6cafcb03c